# showing text on textview thn pausing the main thread

Tags: android

I'd like to know if there is any way I could see the result on the `textview` first before the `thread.sleep` function kicks in.
I am making a quiz application for mcq's in android using sqlite and incase a wrong answer is checked in the radio group I'd like the the textview to display the correct answer and thn go to the next query after a delay,the code is as follows:

```
if (rb1.isChecked() && corrAns.equals("Option1")) {

                counter++;
            //q_no++;
                tvScore.setText("Your score out of 20 is "+counter);


                }
```

by using this code the thread delays but displays the correct option after the query is incremented,is there any way to implement with which I can see the correct answer first b4 the thread sleeps??

```
         if (rb2.isChecked() && corrAns.equals("Option2")) {

                    counter++;
                //  q_no++;     
                    tvScore.setText("Your score out of 20 is "+counter);

                }
         if (rb3.isChecked() && corrAns.equals("Option3")) {

            counter++;
            //q_no++;
             tvScore.setText("Your score out of 20 is "+counter);

        }


        else {
            Pscore.setText("The correct answer was " +corrAns);
            //Thread t=new Thread(){

                    try{

                Thread.sleep(3000);
                    //q_no++;

                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    //finally{
                        //q_no++;
                    //}

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using a TimerTask
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html